# converting a matlab array (MAT-file) to C++ array

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matlab, mat-file

I have a 2-D double-precision array in MATLAB that contains specific data.
I want to use this array in c++, so I save the array in a mat-file.
I know that MATLAB has some c functions that provide reading mat-file in c++ (matdsgn , matOpen , ...), but I don't know how to use them in a c++ program. Actually, I don't know how to use a C library in C++.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Efficient way of converting matlab matrix to array in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591158/efficient-way-of-converting-matlab-matrix-to-array-in-c)

Comment: I'd recommend thinking about whether what you really want to do is create a MAT file on disk and then work with this MAT file in your standalone C++ program, or whether what you would prefer to do is simply pass the MATLAB array to C++ code. If it's the latter, you should look at the MEX interface provided by MATLAB for this purpose: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/introducing-mex-files.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have MATLAB 2017a, there is a built-in function. See this MATHWORKS link: [Math Works](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/creating-a-mat-file-in-c.html)